# How to select a product quantity on one page and pass value to cart.php

Tags: php, cart, woocommerce

Say on front page you have a promotional section that allowed you to increase/decrease the quanitity of products you want, then it calculates the price for you automatically. There's a button I added with an href of

```
 <?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/shop/?add-to-cart=9
```

Which adds a single product to your cart, and takes you to cart.php where you can increase or decrease quantity.

What can I do, or what direction can I take, to get the front-page quantity passed to the cart.php quantity?

For example, my front page code is like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7BDwP/811/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only support it has is: (via URL)

```
?add-to-cart=variation&product_id=1100
```

So you need to make a hidden form element called Qty:

```
<input name="quantity" data-min="1" data-max="0" value="1" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" maxlength="12">
```

But since you have more than one. You would do

```
<form action="/shop/?add-to-cart=variation&amp;product_id=1100" class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Size
<select>
<option value="">Choose an option…</option>
<option value="large">Large</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="small" selected="selected">Small</option>
<option value="x-large">X-Large</option>
</select>

Colour
<select id="pa_colour" name="attribute_pa_colour" style="opacity:0">
<option value="">Choose an option…</option>
<option value="black" selected="selected">Black</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="1104">

<input name="quantity" data-min="1" data-max="0" value="1"
size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" maxlength="12">

<button type="submit" class="button alt">Add to cart</button>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1100"></div>

</form>
```

Just make sure your `Ids` and `Names` are unique, make an jQuery Ajax field which updates that `Qty` value. You can only submit through the form method UNLESS you edit the core `PHP` values and allow `REQUEST` rather than `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var base_url = <?php echo get_home_url(); ?>;

    $('#product').change(function(){
        $('#result').text($(this).val() * 25.99);
        // add this to change the href.  Should really use an ID selector but for your example this works
        $('a').attr('href', base_url+'/shop/?add-to-cart=9&qty='+$('#product').val());
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Adding "&qty=X" doesn't seem to affect cart.php at all, even if I do it manually.

Comment: Seems there is a step missing.  I wrongly assumed the href was pointing to cart.php.  you will need to also pass $_REQUEST['qty'] from (index.php?) whatever page that script is calling on to cart.php.  Look for the add-to-cart variable in that page to see how it's being passed.